# Preserving the 'this' context when using JS Proxy objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a proxy to the global browser window object. The idea is simple - if the caller uses an existing method or property just return that, otherwise use the fake object. Here's the code:

```
var handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
    return name in window ?
      window[name] :
      target[name];
  },
  set: function(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop in window) {
      window[prop] = value
    } else {
      obj[prop] = value
    };
  },
};

var fakeWindow = new Proxy(function() {}, handler);
fakeWindow.foo = 'bar';
console.log(fakeWindow.foo); // outputs 'bar'
fakeWindow.alert('hello'); // error - the alert method is called without the correct this value
```

Problem is, when invoking a method on the proxy object (such as alert in example above), the 'this' value is that of the proxy, not the window.
Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: return window[name].bind(window)

Comment: Only when it's a function though right?

Comment: Also don't forget to `Object.setPrototypeOf(boundFunction, window[name]);` so the caller can access function object properties. By using only bind you create a new function with a context, but strip away all function that where attached to the function object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may bind the context in your getter:

```
get: function (target, name) {
  if (name in window) {
    if (typeof window[name] === "function") return window[name].bind(window);
    return window[name];
  }
  return target[name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on comment from Jonas w:

```
var handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
    return name in window ?
      (typeof window[name] == 'function' ? window[name].bind(window) : window[name]) :
      target[name];
  },
  set: function(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop in window) {
      window[prop] = value
    } else {
      obj[prop] = value
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: Because there are 2 ternary operators.